# Why isn't collision working properly? And why won't it load the next level?

Tags: c#, tags, collision, points, gameobject

This is for a college assignment, the aim is as follows:

For the first level: Collect 3 objects in 30 seconds.
The second level: Collect as many objects as possible in 90 seconds.

I have made the first level mostly, and the collision was working, but it wouldn't load the next level upon completion for some reason.

Here is the code that generates the objects, I can't really figure out how to make it appear properly here, so I'm using a screenshot instead.

[ObjectGeneratorScript pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDOSC.png)

[ObjectGeneratorScript pt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMJk.png)

This has worked at college, but for some reason isn't at home and it's stressing me out as the assignment is due in 2 days and I genuinely can't see waht isn't working. I didn't change anything either since it worked at college.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObjectGeneratorScript : MonoBehaviour {
public static int points;
float radians(float degrees) {
    return (degrees / 180) * Mathf.PI;
}
void makeObjects(float minDistanceFromOriginal, float maxDistanceFromOrigin, PrimitiveType objType, int number, string tag) {
    //Setting up material variables
    Material cubematerial;
    Material spherematerial;
    Material cylindermaterial;
    float angle;
    float distanceFromOrigin;
    float x;
    int i;
    float z;
    GameObject temp;
    //Telling the code what to load for the material variables
    cubematerial = Resources.Load("cubematerial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    spherematerial = Resources.Load("spherematerial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    cylindermaterial = Resources.Load ("cylindermaterial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    for (i=1; i<=number; i++) {
        distanceFromOrigin = minDistanceFromOriginal + Random.value * (maxDistanceFromOrigin - minDistanceFromOriginal);
        angle = Random.Range (0, 360);
        x = distanceFromOrigin * Mathf.Cos (radians (angle));
        z = distanceFromOrigin * Mathf.Sin (radians (angle));
        temp = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (objType);
        temp.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, 0.5f, z);
        Renderer rend = temp.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        //If functions tell the game to load a material for when a certain object is generated
        if (tag=="Cube"){rend.material = cubematerial;}
        if (tag=="Sphere"){rend.material = spherematerial;}
        if (tag=="Cylinder"){rend.material = cylindermaterial;}
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    }


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    print (ObjectGeneratorScript.points);
    if (ObjectGeneratorScript.points == 6) 
    {
        Application.LoadLevel ("lvl2");
    }
}

void onCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "cube") {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        ObjectGeneratorScript.points = ObjectGeneratorScript.points + 1;
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "sphere") {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        ObjectGeneratorScript.points = ObjectGeneratorScript.points + 2;
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "cylinder") {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        ObjectGeneratorScript.points = ObjectGeneratorScript.points + 3;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post the code, not a screenshot. Even if you can't figure the formatting out (and there is a help section for it), someone else can fix it for you.

Comment: OK I'll try, what's wrong with a screenshot though?

Comment: There you go, I couldn't get it to work earlier for some reason.

Comment: Just to name a few reasons: It keeps all of your information on one page, thus more easily accessible to more people (especially lazy/efficient ones who don't want to click a link). Depending on resolutions, screenshots might not scale all that well. And if someone wanted to test your code, they would have to type it all by hand instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: OK, so do you see anything in the code that would stop it from working?